# Is there an R function for unlisting in which one can control the levels of recursion?

Tags: r, list, recursion, nested-lists

I often have nested lists of objects which come from nested `lapply` statements, so that the objects are in the last level. When I want to "flatten" these lists, I use `unlist`; however, sometimes I cannot use `unlist(recursive = T)` because it will also flatten the last object's structure.

Is there any way to control the levels in the list up to which I can apply the unlist recursion? Or is there any other R function that does this?

For example, say I have a list of plots and I want to have them in the same list level to then align all the plots together in a panel.

```
# Example list
library(ggplot2)

l0 <- list(
  l1 = list(
    l2 = list(
      l3.1 = ggplot(data = data.frame()) + ggtitle("p1"),
      l3.2 = ggplot(data = data.frame()) + ggtitle("p2")
    )
  )
)

# What I can do with unlist()
l0.u <- unlist(l0, recursive = F)
l0.u.r <- unlist(l0, recursive = T)

# The desired output
l0.desired <- unlist(unlist(l0, recursive = F),recursive = F)
```

Comment: You don't have to use `lapply` to iterate over an object.  You can use a `for` loop, and produce exactly the structure you want.  It's likely to be faster than `lapply` followed by some `unlist` variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several other solutions using `rrapply()` (in package `rrapply`), which has a dedicated option `how = "flatten"` to flatten a nested list based on some `condition` function:

```
## by class (not a pure list)
rrapply::rrapply(
  l0,
  condition = \(x) !inherits(x, "list"),
  classes = c("list", "ANY"),
  how = "flatten"
)

## by class (ggplot object)
rrapply::rrapply(
  l0,
  condition = ggplot2::is.ggplot,
  classes = c("list", "ANY"),
  how = "flatten"
)

## by name
rrapply::rrapply(
  l0,
  condition = \(x, .xname) grepl("l3", .xname),
  classes = c("list", "ANY"),
  how = "flatten"
)

## by level of nesting
rrapply::rrapply(
  l0,
  condition = \(x, .xpos) length(.xpos) == 3,
  classes = c("list", "ANY"),
  how = "flatten"
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a recursive function that keeps unlisting without recursion until class is *ggplot*:

```
f <- function(x){
  if(all(sapply(x, function(i) inherits(i, c("gg", "ggplot"))))) {
    x
  } else f(unlist(x, recursive = FALSE))
}

x <- f(l0)

names(x)
# [1] "l1.l2.l3.1" "l1.l2.l3.2"

# plot 1st plot
x$l1.l2.l3.1

# plot 2nd plot
x$l1.l2.l3.2
```

Comment: Testing inheritance via `class` is discouraged. You can do the test much simpler using `inherits()`: `if (inherits(x, c("gg", "ggplot")))`. And since you use `if…else` you don’t need the `return()` call.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks, edited. Anyway to avoid sapply? (btw, feel free to edit)

Comment: Hm. Looks like I completely misunderstood the function, because I thought that we didn’t need the `all(sapply(…))` at all. Now I’m confused as to *why* we need it …

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think they want to get to the plots. But as the ggplot is a list, we can't just use unlist, so I am stopping once the list only contains ggplots.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But shouldn’t it be possible to stop “one level further down”, i.e. at the individual ggplot object, rather than at the list containing these? I currently don’t see *how* but I feel that it *should* work.

Comment: I will leave it to OP for now.

Comment: @zx8754, yes, this solves the problem! (which is to get to the deepest object without applying `unlist` to it). I guess there is no way to do this agnostically, without having to know the classes of the final object?

Comment: @Papyrus, you can use `length(oldClass(x)) == 0` to identify objects with no explicit class set.